# Endless recyclerview with admob ads

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to develop an app that implements infinite scrolling recyclerview which loads 50 items when recyclerview reaches bottom and admob native ads is placed between every 10 items. The problem is on scroll,I get null pointer exception.I have tried to figure out the logic to add new item on onscroll method in activity class. Here is the image of the exception

[image]

and code of activity and adapter class.

Activity class:

```
// A Native Express ad is placed in every nth position in the RecyclerView.
public static final int ITEMS_PER_AD = 10;

// The Native Express ad height.
private static final int NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_HEIGHT = 150;

// The Native Express ad unit ID.
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1072772517";

// The RecyclerView that holds and displays Native Express ads and menu items.
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

// List of Native Express ads and MenuItems that populate the RecyclerView.
private List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems = new ArrayList<>();
private int loadCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recyclerview_with_ads);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    // Use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView.
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // Specify a linear layout manager.
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    generateData();

    // Update the RecyclerView item's list with menu items and Native Express ads.
    addNativeExpressAds();
    setUpAndLoadNativeExpressAds();

    // Specify an adapter.
    final RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(RecyclerviewWithAds.this, mRecyclerViewItems, mRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    //load data
                    //cant figure out the logic here.
                    Log.e("loadcount", "" + (loadCount + 1));
                    loadCount++;
                    Log.e("itemsList", "" + mRecyclerViewItems.size());

                    final int index = mRecyclerViewItems.size() - ((6 * loadCount) - (loadCount - 1));

                    Log.e("Modulus", "" + (mRecyclerViewItems.size() % ITEMS_PER_AD));
                    Log.e("index", "" + index);
                    final int end = index + 50;

                    for (int i = index; i <= end; i++) {
                        mRecyclerViewItems.add(new MenuItem("name " + i));
                    }
                    for (int i = (index + (ITEMS_PER_AD - (loadCount - 1))); i <= end; i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {
                        final NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(RecyclerviewWithAds.this);
                        Log.e("ads position", "" + i);
                        mRecyclerViewItems.add(i, adView);
                    }


                    mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final float scale = RecyclerviewWithAds.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                            int i;
                            // Set the ad size and ad unit ID for each Native Express ad in the items list.
                            for (i = (index + (ITEMS_PER_AD - (loadCount -1))); i <= end; i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {
                                final NativeExpressAdView adView =
                                        (NativeExpressAdView) mRecyclerViewItems.get(i);
                                final CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.ad_card_view);
                                final int adWidth = cardView.getWidth() - cardView.getPaddingLeft()
                                        - cardView.getPaddingRight();
                                AdSize adSize = new AdSize((int) (adWidth / scale), NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_HEIGHT);
                                adView.setAdSize(adSize);
                                adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
                            }

                            // Load the first Native Express ad in the items list.
                            loadNativeExpressAd(0);
                        }
                    });

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter.setLoaded();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Adds Native Express ads to the items list.
 */
public void generateData() {


    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

        mRecyclerViewItems.add(new MenuItem("name " + i));

    }
}

private void addNativeExpressAds() {

    // Loop through the items array and place a new Native Express ad in every ith position in
    // the items List.
    for (int i = 0; i <= mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {
        final NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(RecyclerviewWithAds.this);
        mRecyclerViewItems.add(i, adView);
    }
}


/**
 * Sets up and loads the Native Express ads.
 */
private void setUpAndLoadNativeExpressAds() {
    // Use a Runnable to ensure that the RecyclerView has been laid out before setting the
    // ad size for the Native Express ad. This allows us to set the Native Express ad's
    // width to match the full width of the RecyclerView.
    mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final float scale = RecyclerviewWithAds.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            // Set the ad size and ad unit ID for each Native Express ad in the items list.
            for (int i = 0; i <= mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {
                final NativeExpressAdView adView =
                        (NativeExpressAdView) mRecyclerViewItems.get(i);
                final CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.ad_card_view);
                final int adWidth = cardView.getWidth() - cardView.getPaddingLeft()
                        - cardView.getPaddingRight();
                AdSize adSize = new AdSize((int) (adWidth / scale), NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_HEIGHT);
                adView.setAdSize(adSize);
                adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
            }

            // Load the first Native Express ad in the items list.
            loadNativeExpressAd(0);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Loads the Native Express ads in the items list.
 */
private void loadNativeExpressAd(final int index) {

    if (index >= mRecyclerViewItems.size()) {
        return;
    }

    Object item = mRecyclerViewItems.get(index);
    if (!(item instanceof NativeExpressAdView)) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Expected item at index " + index + " to be a Native"
                + " Express ad.");
    }

    final NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) item;

    // Set an AdListener on the NativeExpressAdView to wait for the previous Native Express ad
    // to finish loading before loading the next ad in the items list.
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            // The previous Native Express ad loaded successfully, call this method again to
            // load the next ad in the items list.
            loadNativeExpressAd(index + ITEMS_PER_AD);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // The previous Native Express ad failed to load. Call this method again to load
            // the next ad in the items list.
            Log.e("MainActivity", "The previous Native Express ad failed to load. Attempting to"
                    + " load the next Native Express ad in the items list.");
            loadNativeExpressAd(index + ITEMS_PER_AD);
        }
    });

    // Load the Native Express ad.
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
```

Adapter class:

```
// A menu item view type.
private static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;

// The Native Express ad view type.
private static final int NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

// An Activity's Context.
private final Context mContext;

// The list of Native Express ads and menu items.
private final List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems;


private int visibleThreshold = 5;
private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
private boolean isLoading;

private OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener;

/**
 * For this example app, the recyclerViewItems list contains only
 * {@link MenuItem} and {@link NativeExpressAdView} types.
 */
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Object> recyclerViewItems,RecyclerView mRecyclerView) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mRecyclerViewItems = recyclerViewItems;

    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0) {
                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }

        }
    });
}

/**
 * The {@link MenuItemViewHolder} class.
 * Provides a reference to each view in the menu item view.
 */
public class MenuItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView menuItemName;
    private TextView menuItemDescription;
    private TextView menuItemPrice;
    private TextView menuItemCategory;
    private ImageView menuItemImage;

    MenuItemViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        menuItemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_image);
        menuItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_name);
        menuItemPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_price);
        menuItemCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_category);
        menuItemDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_description);
    }
}

/**
 * The {@link NativeExpressAdViewHolder} class.
 */
public class NativeExpressAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    NativeExpressAdViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mRecyclerViewItems.size();
}

/**
 * Determines the view type for the given position.
 */
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position % RecyclerviewWithAds.ITEMS_PER_AD == 0) ? NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE
            : MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
}

/**
 * Creates a new view for a menu item view or a Native Express ad view
 * based on the viewType. This method is invoked by the layout manager.
 */
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
            View menuItemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.menu_item_container, viewGroup, false);
            return new MenuItemViewHolder(menuItemLayoutView);
        case NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            // fall through
        default:
            View nativeExpressLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(
                    viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_express_ad_container,
                    viewGroup, false);
            return new NativeExpressAdViewHolder(nativeExpressLayoutView);
    }

}

/**
 *  Replaces the content in the views that make up the menu item view and the
 *  Native Express ad view. This method is invoked by the layout manager.
 */
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
        case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
            MenuItemViewHolder menuItemHolder = (MenuItemViewHolder) holder;
            MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);

            // Get the menu item image resource ID.

            // Add the menu item details to the menu item view.
            menuItemHolder.menuItemName.setText(menuItem.getName());
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "position : "+ position , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            break;
        case NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            // fall through
        default:
            NativeExpressAdViewHolder nativeExpressHolder =
                    (NativeExpressAdViewHolder) holder;
            NativeExpressAdView adView =
                    (NativeExpressAdView) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);
            ViewGroup adCardView = (ViewGroup) nativeExpressHolder.itemView;
            // The NativeExpressAdViewHolder recycled by the RecyclerView may be a different
            // instance than the one used previously for this position. Clear the
            // NativeExpressAdViewHolder of any subviews in case it has a different
            // AdView associated with it, and make sure the AdView for this position doesn't
            // already have a parent of a different recycled NativeExpressAdViewHolder.
            if (adCardView.getChildCount() > 0) {
                adCardView.removeAllViews();
            }
            if (adView.getParent() != null) {
                ((ViewGroup) adView.getParent()).removeView(adView);
            }

            // Add the Native Express ad to the native express ad view.
            adCardView.addView(adView);
    }
}

//Extra methods
public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener) {
    this.mOnLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener;
}


public void setLoaded() {
    isLoading = false;
}
```

I would be very thankful if somebody would help me implement this effectively.